# New instance of Excel does not see already opened instance

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I have Avizo.xlt with one Worksheet and a code which intended to put this WS inside already opened document, which is SLK report made by our ancient ERP system, and close this document.

Everything worked fine before 2007 widespread over users' desktops. My code:

```vb
Public Sub format_avizo3()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    For Each Wb In Workbooks
        Select Case Wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
        Case "F004CP000V001", "F004CP000V003", "F004CP000V004":
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:I22").Copy
            'some extra code
        End Select
    Next Wb
    ThisWorkbook.Close False
End Sub
```

Now, Excel with new document, doesn't see already opened Excel. How can I force it to find itself?

Workaround: leave Excel opened before process start and it will work.

Comment: Are the documents and locations trusted in the Trust Center? Are macros enabled in Macro Security settings? Also, you may need to debug your code in case some syntax changed.

Comment: Documents not trusted. Macros are enabled.

Comment: Have you tried trusting the document?

Comment: No... if I trust it, the problem will gone? I thought there is some setting in the system. Also I forgot to tell that if Excel is left opened before the process starts, the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a system limitation and there is no a quick solution.

You can either open all workbooks in one Excel instance, or use a solution from `ForEachLoop`. It works, though it involves a lot of code. Please follow the link below for more details:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971473/can-vba-reach-across-instances-of-excel